# How can I pass a class method to another function like what happen in thread constructor

Tags: c++, function-pointers, argument-passing

I want to pass a class method to another function and I wrote these codes:

```
class x {
   executeQuery(std::string query, int (*f)(void* cpuInfo, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName))
   {
          int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), &f, 0, &errMessage);
          ...
   }
};
```

The above code shows the function that I called from class constructor!

```
myclass()
{
    xObject->executeQuery("test", &(myclass::myfunction));
}
```

And this part of code shows how I pass myfunction to that method! But, during compile time I got this error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.
```

I called a thread constructor by same syntax! But it sounds like that the thread constructor makes a new function pointer that I can't understand! Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem with/without thread solution?
The below code shows the thread constructor header:

```
  template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
  explicit 
  thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
  {
    _M_start_thread(_M_make_routine(std::__bind_simple(
            std::forward<_Callable>(__f),
            std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)));
  }
```

Comment: It´s constructor, not contractor or constrator. And with normal func pointers, what you want is not possible.

Comment: OK that was just a spelling mistake!

Comment: @HRH _'OK that was just a spelling mistake!'_ Yes multiple times. Correct wording and proper english matter here. Edit your question please, to correct it.

Comment: How can `executeQuery` be the constructor of `class x`?

Comment: It is not the constructor of `class x`, why do you ask this? I just used thread constructor as an example to show where my related solution exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

In your example you use the function pointer with `sqlite3_exec`. `sqlite3_exec` requires a C-style function as argument `callback`. You can *not* use a pointer to a class member function here!

Something like this might be a work-around. But beware of thread-safty:

```
namespace wrap {
    typedef std::function<int(void*,int,char**,char**)> QueryFunction;
    inline QueryFunction& function() {
        static QueryFunction f;
        return f;
    }
    void callback(void* cpuInfo, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName);
}

void wrap::callback(void* cpuInfo, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName) {
     function()(cpuInfo, argc, argv, azColName);
}


class x {
   executeQuery(std::string query, QueryFunction f)
   {
        wrap::function() = f;
        int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), &wrap::callback, 0, &errMessage);
        ...
   }
};

MyClass* obj = ...;
xObject->executeQuery("test", std::bind(myclass::myfunction, obj));
```

**Old answer**:

You can use `std::function` to wrap class member functions (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)):

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<int(void*,int,char**,char**)> QueryFunction;

class x {
public:
    void executeQuery(std::string query, QueryFunction f) {
        f(ptr,0,"hello","test"); // call function
    }
};

MyClass* obj = ...;
using std::placeholders;
xObject->executeQuery("test", std::bind(myclass::myfunction, obj, _1, _2, _3, _4));
```

In order to give a pointer to a class member function, you need to also provide an object on which the member function should be called.

`std::bind` allows you to do this (and even more). In the case above, the first argument to `std::bind` is the pointer to the class member function and the second argument is the object which shall be used to call the function. The following arguments `_1`, ... are placeholders for arguments you will provide later when using the function pointer.

Comment: _1, _2, _3, _4 are unnecessary, aren't they?

Comment: @HRH: I think your actual problem lies somewhere and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your answer does not work for me and I got a compile error! anyway....

Answer (score 0):

`std::thread` and many other libraries don't receive function pointer. They receive **functor**.

functor is all things which can be called with `()` operator. So, function pointer is functor:

```
void (*pf)();

// we can do it
pf();
```

We also can call the object which overloads `operator ()`.

```
struct Functor
{
    void operator ()();
};
Funtor f;

// we also can do it
f();
```

Member function pointer is not functor. (you can't `mpf(this);`. `this->*mpf();` is correct.) However, the constructor of `std::thread` performs *bind*.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> // for std::bind

template <typename F>
void call_functor(F f)
{
    f();
}

void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
struct bar { void operator ()() { std::cout << "bar\n"; } };

void WithParam(int i) { std::cout << "param : " << i << "\n"; }

class Cls
{
public:
    void member() { std::cout << "Cls::member\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    // we can do these, because both foo and b are functor.
    bar b;
    call_functor(foo);
    call_functor(b);

    // bind `123`
    call_functor(std::bind(WithParam, 123));

    // bind `c`
    Cls c;
    call_functor(std::bind(&Cls::member, &c /* this pointer */));
}
```

Look this: `call_functor(std::bind(WithParam, 123));`. Although `WithParam` cannot be called with `f()` because it has a parameter, we can use `WithParam` by *binding* its parameter to `123`.

`std::bind` can perform not only binding parameter, but also binding *this pointer* with member function pointer. So we also can do this: `call_functor(std::bind(&Cls::member, &c /* this pointer */));`.

---

We cannot know the *type* of all functors. For example: `void (*)()`, `struct bar`, or `std::bind`...

So, to receive functor as parameter, we should use template. For example, look at `std::thread`'s constructor:

```
template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
explicit 
thread(_Callable&& __f, // <-- here
    ...
```

In your case, you should do like this:

```
class x
{
public:
    template <typename Functor>
    void executeQuery(std::string query, Functor f)
    {
        ...
        int result = f(cpuInfo, argc, argv, azColName);
        ...
    }
};

...

myclass()
{
    xObject->executeQuery("test", std::bind(&myclass::myfunction, this));
}
```

---

Do you mind use template (Maybe you want to hide the implementation of `executeQuery`)? Then, there's another solution, `std::function<>`. it's polymorphism-wrapper to functor. It is a little slower than functor, but it can be good solution if you mind use template.

```
class x
{
public:
    void executeQuery(std::string query,
        const std::function<int ()(void*, int, char**, char**)> &f);
};
```

Usage is *almost* equal to functor. (maybe you need to explicit-cast into `std::function<>`) In fact, `std::function` is functor, too! (it can be called with `()` operator..)

---

**edit:** Ummm.. I've just noticed you're using `f` like this:

```
int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), &f, 0, &errMessage);
```

Maybe the third parameter of `sqlite3_exec` is function pointer, right? It'll become complicated..

According to [here](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html), the 4th argument of `sqlite3_exec` will be passed into `f` as the 1st argument. Then, we can write code like this:

```
// header file of `class x`
class x
{
private:
    static void ExecuteQuery_Callback(void *param, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName);

    // use std::function<>
    typedef std::function<int (void*, int, char**, char**)> ExecQueryFunctor;
    void executeQuery_impl(std::string query, const ExecQueryFunctor &f);
public:
    // wrapper
    template <typename F> void executeQuery(std::string query, F f)
    {
        executeQuery_impl(query, ExecQueryFunctor(f));
    }
};

// .cpp file of `class x`
void x::executeQuery_impl(std::string query, const x::ExecQueryFunctor &f)
{
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), ExecuteQuery_Callback, &f, &errMessage);
    ...
}

void x::ExecuteQuery_Callback(void *param, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    const ExecQueryFunctor *pfunctor = (const ExecQueryFunctor *)param;
    (*pfunctor)(NULL, argc, argv, azColName);
}
```

---

**edit2:** Um, I see the problem.. For one thing, it works well if you do this:

```
    xObject->executeQuery("test", std::bind(&myclass::myfunction, this));
```

Change into:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
...

    xObject->executeQuery("test", std::bind(&myclass::myfunction, this, _1, _2, _3, _4));
```

`_1`, `_2`, `_3`, `_4` are *placeholders*. (If you want to know about placeholders, search google..)

In this case, I don't think placeholders are required, But if there's no placeholders, error occurs...

---

**edit3:** the reason of why we should use placeholders: [Why are placeholders required in std::bind in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934338/why-are-placeholders-required-in-stdbind-in-this-case)

Comment: there is another callable object: lamda expression

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work! I try to use your solution and the result is like this: 1. your typedef doesn't work and I had to change it to: `typedef std::function<int (void*, int, char**, char**)> ExecQueryFunctor;` 2. after writing the code my compiler say this: `error: no matching function for call to ‘x::executeQuery(std::string&, std::_Bind_helper<false, int (myclass::*)(void*, int, char**, char**), mycalss* const>::type)`

Comment: @texasbruce I'm trying to explain as easily as possible, So I didn't mention lambda...

Answer (score 0):

After much hanging around and trying out possible solutions, I found that there is no solution for my problem. I had a conversation with a professional c++ programmer(Hedayat Vatankhah) and he explained since a method of a class has a special address in c++, you can't pass its pointer to a c function (like `sqlite3_exec`) that expect an absolute address.
BTW, it sounds like that there is an extension for gcc that can convert method address to absolute address (but I leave this solution and I try some simple sqlite3 function to create new version of sqlite3_exec)